# AWS lambda function does not find the main app when running a local sam invoke command. How do I make sam invoke find the app.py application?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, sam

The command which fails is:

```
/usr/local/bin/sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --template /home/peter/Dropbox2/Dropbox/clothes_recco/production/bodyestimate/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml --event "/tmp/[Local] BodyEstimate-event109.json"
```

and it outputs an error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'bodyestimate'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "3b3bb307-9647-4171-99a6-24dae52b3b55", "stackTrace": []}END
```

My lambda function structure is:

```
bodyestimate/
   bodyestimate/
       template.yaml
       packaged.yaml
       app.py
       requirements.txt
       __init__.py
       Dockerfile
   test/
      unit/ 
         test_handler.py
```

The pytests pass when I run the **test_handler.py** which imports the app.py.
It seems to me that sam invoke does not find the main app function when the project is ran as a programme.

Any thoughts on how I can get the sam local invoke to recognise the app in app.py?

My template.yaml file is below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question.

Comment: Is it the same error if you try with the template in the bodyestimate (/home/peter/Dropbox2/Dropbox/clothes_recco/production/bodyestimate/template.yaml) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to do with the app file not being copied into the container.

Adding a '''COPY app.py ./''' into the docker file solved the problem!